# cakephp find query conditions on associated model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3

I have a model `User` and a model `Role` in a CakePHP application. The association between the two models is the following:

```
User $belongsTo Role
Role $hasMany User
```

I want to make a query on the `User` model to find all users with a specific role (let's say the role Supervisor). I did my query like this:

```
$supervisors = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Role' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Role.name' => 'Supervisor'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

But the above query returns me all the users in my users table. It does not return only the users with role Supervisor. I know that if I do two queries, one on the `Role` model to find the id of the role type 'Supervisor' and then do another query on the User model and pass the id of the supervisor role record in the conditions on my User model like this:

```
$supervisor_role_id = $this->Role->field('id', array('Role.name' => 'Supervisor'));

$supervisors = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.role_id' => $supervisor_role_id
    )
));
```

The above queries will give me the desired result. But I don't wanna do 2 queries to do this. Why doesn't the first approach work. Any idea please?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

**The reason your attempt didn't work**

CakePHP's `Containble` Behavior creates separate queries for each model.  So - what you did was basically described like this:  "Find all Users.  Also find any Roles with the name of 'Supervisor". As you can see, there is no condition that crosses between the two.

So, you can do one of the following:

**1)  [easy way] Query the other way around**

Query from the `Role` model and contain it's user(s).  This pulls the role you want (based on your provided conditions) then contains any/all of it's users.

Note - if you've already loaded the 'User' model (or it's been loaded by default because you're in the `UsersController`), you can run your find like this:  `$this->User->Role->find(.....`  - so you don't have to load the `Role` model separately.

**2)  Use JOINs (see [CakePHP Book on Joining Tables](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables))**

This allows you to limit the result of a parent model based on it's associated data.

Comment: "User $belongsTo Role" So in this case it would actually be correct to query the user and left join the role. It should not create a separate query here if configured correctly.

Comment: @mark - I mentioned he could use Joins (#2).  Or, he could just reverse the query and use Containable.  Lots of options.